# How fast could a Mini Cooper go in a vacuum?

Tags: automotive-engineering, vacuum, car

Lord Evulz just stole the Earth's atmosphere. Our hero must race his trusty old Mini - which he had already prepared to be airtight, to ensure the tires do not explode, with pre-packaged oxygen to supply his fuel with, etcetera... - to the last escape rocket before his air supply runs out.

Assume regular Earth highway conditions - (with no traffic because everybody asphyxiated to death) - with the only difference that there is no air resistance. What are the limiting factors on the car's top speed? And what velocity might be attained?

If the specific model matters much, take the 1977 British Leyland Mini 1000 - because it is Mr Bean's car and I fully expect him to find a way to drive it into orbit.

Comment: Disclaimer: I was having much difficulty deciding whether this question belongs in the Physics stack exchange, the Worldbuilding one, or this one. I went here because I expect more members of this SE to know how fast the different parts of the car can physically rotate - but if it's not that suitable for here, I'd like to know.

Comment: Most likely, the limiting factor will be the maximum engine RPM. Even a formula 1 race engine can only run up to about 15,000 RPM, compared with the red line speed of around 7,000 for your engine.

Comment: With no air resistance, then the force the engine is able to put out is only countered by static friction and then rolling friction. The complexity comes from the fact that all the moving pieces contribute some amount of friction. I don't understand the second question - are you asking what typical max speeds can be expected?

Comment: @blacksmith37 The OP says there is  "pre-packaged oxygen to supply his fuel with, etcetera."

Comment: Engine cooling would be a problem. You'd manage about ten miles before overheating.

Comment: @J.Ari Yes, that's what I meant. It was a wordy way of asking how fast this thing would go. And I'm fine with an order of magnitude estimation. Are we talking Formula 1 speeds, rocket car speeds, or Concorde speeds?

Comment: @alephzero With 7000 RPM and a typical wheel diameter of 33 inches, Mach 1 would be the ceiling. Though I am not sure if the engine is actually mechanically limited to the red line, or if that's just the point where you as a driver are warned to seriously consider what you're doing.

Comment: @PhilSweet That's an interesting point. Are you saying that the extreme convective cooling at these speeds wouldn't be enough or that the thinner atmosphere prevents effective heat transfer?

Comment: No air = nowhere for the heat to go. Mega RPM = more friction = more heat, specifically in areas not expected to be so hot. In short, I think this is a worldbuildinb question as the answer depends primarily on what level of suspension of disbelief the rest of your story is pitched at.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I mean "it would melt after five minutes" _would_ be a valid answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Top speed increases from 81 to 89 mph.

The air drag force is 0.5 x air density x drag area * speed^2. 
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile_drag_coefficient).  Therefore drag power is 0.5 x air density x drag area * speed^3.  The cube term on speed is very important, i.e. doubling speed requires 8 times more power to overcome air resistance.  At highway speeds, air resistance becomes dominant.

According to https://www.automobile-catalog.com/auta_details1.php, the 1977 Mini has an *Estimated* drag area of 0.788 m^2

Doing the math, this means that at the top speed of 81 mph, overcoming air drag requires about 31 HP. According to same website, the 1977 Mini has 39 net HP.  Therefore, at top speed, 79% of the engine's power is being used to overcome air resistance.

So, in theory, removing air resistance would give a huge amount of extra available power.  However, based on the same site again , max horsepower occurs at 4750 RPM, whereas the engine redline is 5200 rpm.  Therefore, only a modest increase of 9% is possible.  Top speed would be 89 mph.

To achieve a higher max speed, you would need to redesign the gearbox to take advantage of the reduced air drag. I.e. give a higher max velocity for the same engine speed by using a different gear ratio.

Comment: A lot less than I was expecting, but thanks for providing the calculations :)

Answer (score 2):

In an atmosphere, the top speed is probably limited by air resistance more than anything, but in a vacuum it would be limited by other factors. Rolling resistance is a major effect that would definitely limit speed. As discussed in the comments, engine rpm would also be a limit if using stock gear ratios.

According to a quick google search, the top speed of the Mini is 81 mph stock- actually quite impressive for a British economy car from the 70s. Whether the limiting factor proves to be rolling resistance or engine redline, it won't increase much.

I would expect less than 100mph, probably like 95 before the decreased power at high rpms, rolling resistance, and internal friction(wheel bearings, CV joints, transmission) conspire to prevent you from reaching higher speeds. This, of course, assumes that your engine hasn't melted down yet from lack of cooling, but I trust Mr Bean to have installed a sufficient system(ice tank in the cabin?)